# Use .Net Framework class in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dllimport, signedxml, system.security

Hy Everyone!

I'm developing a .Net Core class library project, but I have to use a class from .Net Framework DLL called `System.Security`, which is unavailable in Core.
(The class is the `SignedXml.cs` in `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` namespace. - Yes I know that namespace  and class exists in Core too, but the `SignedXml` is not the same, there are some private fields which are missing (`m_refProcessed`, `m_refLevelCache` etc.).)

I have to use the old class.

Is there any solution to import `System.Security` in my Core project and extend the `SignedXml` class? Or just import the `SignedXml` class?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you care if some private fields are missing? That's just an implementation issue.

Comment: `I have to use the old class.` why? That's the most important information - without it the question can't be answered. You *don't* need any of those private fields, not even for serialization. Serializing a signed XML means saving the *signed XML string*, not the class used to produce it.

Comment: Did you use BinaryFormatter perhaps? That's a no-no even in .NET Old

Comment: Even with .NET Old, *any* patch could change the implementation (that's why they exist) so your code could break by any .NET Old patch delivered through Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what you want to do, but, it obviously failed, what you could do, is adding a new .net framework solution to the project, and call it when needed, that way you'll be able to use the library you need.

Comment: In short "don't use .NET Core". That's not a goog answer though, especially since we don't know what the *real* problem is. Private fields don't matter

Answer (score 0):

If you check in documentation, Microsoft is not describing any differences between the .NET Core and the .NET Framework version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml?view=netcore-3.1

You should never manipulate private fields, it would be dangerous for the maintainability of your code.

I see that you are talking about an "Old class", when you come to security classes, it's better to stay up to date with latest version. Maybe that the difference is coming from a corrected flaws in the code. It is then a good idea to keep the latest one.

Anyway, .NET Core and .NET framework are not designed to be compatible. On paper, it should be possible when they will release .NET framework 5.0.

Comment: A *lot* of missing interfaces were reintroduced in .NET Core 3.1. Compatibility never takes *private* fields into account and none of those classes should be expected to have the same implementation as the old ones. .NET Core 5.0 isn't going to change that.

Comment: What I mean is that once we have .net 5.0, the difference between .net framework and .net core will not be a problem anymore as only .net 5.0 will be maintained. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/ Of course, I agree that the internal implementation may change, but the public contract of the class will not change between versions. That's why private fields should not be used.